# jQuery: Show/Hide Elements based on Selected Option from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-selectors

UPDATE: The original question asked was answered. However, the code revealed for all. So, I've modified my question below:

So I have the following dynamically generated html via php

```
<div class="image-link link-posttypes mainSelector1">
    <select id="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][post_type]" name="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][post_type]">
        <option value="">default</option>
        <option value="post" class="post-type">Post</option><option value="page" class="post-type">Page</option><option value="dp_menu_items" class="post-type">Menu Items</option>
        <option value="wps_employees" class="post-type">Employees</option><option value="custom-link">Custom Link</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="image-link link-pages1">
    <select id="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][page_id]" name="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][page_id]">
        <option value="50" class="level-0">About</option>
        <option value="65" class="level-0">Contact</option>
        <option value="2" class="level-0">Sample Page</option>
        <option value="60" class="level-0">Staff</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="image-link link-posts1">
    <select onchange="javascript:dropdown_post_js(this)" id="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][post_id]" name="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][post_id]">
        <option value="http://localhost/tomatopie/?p=1" class="level-0">Hello world!</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="image-link link-custom1">
    <input type="text" size="25" value="" name="wp_accordion_images[20110630022615][image_links_to]">
</div>
```

***THEN IT REPEATS four times: where the #1 goes to 2..3...4 (max to 4 at this time).

I have the ability to label div .classes, select #ids, and option classes. However, what I want to be able to do is based on the option selected from div .link-posttypes, I want to reveal .link-pages (if page is selected) or .link-posts (if post is selected) and .link-custom for all others (except the default).

So as written on the screen there should only be the initial div, and once the user selects an item, the appropriate div appears.

I have never developed anything in jQuery or javascript. This is my maiden voyage. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

***Also, this will be loaded via an external js file.

Comment: Question UPDATED. Original answers were right but my question was inaccurate. There are four versions of this and the JS needs to only reveal the appropriate class (.link-posts2) based on the mainSelector#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the final answer that worked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".link-posttypes select").change(function(){
   var selectedVal = $(":selected",this).val();

   if(selectedVal=="post"){
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-pages").hide();
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-posts").slideDown('slow');
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-custom").hide();
   }else if(selectedVal=="page"){
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-pages").slideDown('slow');
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-posts").hide();
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-custom").hide();
   }else if(selectedVal!=""){
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-pages").hide();
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-posts").hide();
        $(this).parent().next().nextAll(".link-custom").slideDown('slow');
   }else{
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-pages").hide();
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-posts").hide();
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".link-custom").hide();
   }
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".image-content select").change(function(){
   var selectedVal = $(":selected",this).val();

   if(selectedVal=="content-limit"){
        $(this).parent().next().nextAll(".content-limit-chars").slideDown('slow');
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".content-custom").hide();
   }else if(selectedVal=="custom-content"){
        $(this).parent().nextAll(".content-limit-chars").hide();
        $(this).parent().next().nextAll(".content-custom").slideDown('slow');
   }
});
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consider formatting your answer so that its much more readable. Also, don't forget to accept an answer (even if its your own).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're outputting proper IDs, you can do something like this (note I replaced the id):

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    // hide all the divs except the posttypes
    $('.image-link').not('.link-posttypes').hide();
    $('#wp_accordion_images_20110630022615_post_type').change(function() {
        var divSelector = '.link-' + $(this).val();
        $('.image-link').not('.link-posttypes').hide();
        $(divSelector).show();

    });
  });
```

Also, consider changing your `options` like this:

```
<option value="posts" class="post-type">Post</option>
<option value="pages" class="post-type">Page</option>
<option value="menu_items" class="post-type">Menu Items</option>        
<option value="wps_employees" class="post-type">Employees</option>
<option value="custom">Custom Link</option>
```

Here's a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/JrPeR/

Comment: I think for your last line of JS you meant `$('.image-link').not(divSelector).hide();` Otherwise you hide the thing you just show()ed.

Comment: @Don: I edited afterwards to hide everything first and then show the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

There's my understandable jquery script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".link-pages").hide();
    $(".link-posts").hide();
    $(".link-custom").hide();
    $(".link-posttypes select").change(function(){
       var selectedVal = $(":selected",this).val();
       if(selectedVal=="post"){
            $(".link-pages").hide();
            $(".link-posts").show();
            $(".link-custom").hide();
       }else if(selectedVal=="page"){
            $(".link-pages").show();
            $(".link-posts").hide();
            $(".link-custom").hide();
       }else if(selectedVal!=""){
            $(".link-pages").hide();
            $(".link-posts").hide();
            $(".link-custom").show();
       }else{
            $(".link-pages").hide();
            $(".link-posts").hide();
            $(".link-custom").hide();
       }
    });
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/blackship/4DJ74/). Take me couple minute to make you easy to understand. Have fun.

Comment: This is the version that worked though I had to change the first line: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: ship Thanks. Can you please modify?

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JrPeR/3/

added a conditional so if its not the two variables it defaults to the custom.